# How do I adjust the mousewheel scroll speed on wayland on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: mouse, 17.10, scrolling, wayland, mouse-wheel

I have a logitech M500 mouse (M-U0007) and am running the default wayland (I think?) gnome desktop on 17.10. The scrollwheel speed is quite slow and I'd like to boost it a little. I found a few posts on setting it for X windows but how do I adjust it for Wayland? There's no option under Settings|Devices|Mouse&Touchpad. There's just a Mouse Speed for screen movement and a Natural Scrolling directionality available to change.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem and the only answers I've found are for changing the scroll speed in Firefox.

Comment: Is there any update on this? Or is it still not possible to change the scroll speed on Wayland?